# Get current record (slug) in bolt extension

Tags: bolt-cms

How I can get the content type and the current slug from a bolt extension? (php).
Something like this $this->app['content']['current']['slug'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the record on to the twig function: `{{ mytwigextension(record) }}`.